# angularjs performance : watch on same expression/variable more than once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

Because of the pattern of my code, i have to apply the watch on the same variable again and again..does this cause any performance problem or memory leak. I have two watch in my code, if anything changes in the first watch it calls a function which applies the watch again on the same variable. my code looks as below, watch is applied on actualHeight again when a new class with name .sameHeight is added. I want to know if this causes any memory leak or performance issue..if yes how to solve this..

```
.directive("sameHeight", function () { //declaration; identifier master
    function link(scope, element) { //scope we are in, element we are bound to

        var inWatch = false;       

        var helper = function () {
            $(element).find('.sameHeight').each(function () {
                var s = angular.element(this).scope();

                console.log('element ' + this.id + ' = ');
                console.log(s);
                scope.$watch(function () { return s.actualHeight; }, function (oldValue, newValue) {

                    var maxHeight = 0;
                    // get the max height which can be set.
                    $(element).find('.sameHeight').each(function () {
                        var sc = angular.element(this).scope();
                        if (maxHeight < sc.actualHeight) {
                            maxHeight = sc.actualHeight;
                        }
                    });

                    // set the interpolated height.
                    $(element).find('.sameHeight').each(function () {
                        var scp = angular.element(this).scope();
                        scp.interpolatedHeight = maxHeight;
                    });
                    console.log('max height is = ' + maxHeight);
                });
            });
        };

        scope.$watch(function () { return $(element).find('.sameHeight').length; }, function (oldValue, newValue) {
            helper();
        });
```